# How to take a item selected from a list a random to reveal corresponding list onload?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a menu for a portfolio website. It will consist of three columns 'medium', 'subject' and 'project'. Each project will have a preview image when hovered over.

You can see what I've got so far on "rintintin.colorado.edu/~djigania"
Take a look at the example of 'photography'-->'architectural'-->'guggenheim'

This is the way the page will look but every refresh or return to the homepage will randomly show a different project.

This the sequence of events I imagine would happen. Please let me know if there is a better way of approaching this.
1. Onload a random item from the 'medium' list is selected
2. This random selection is automatically clicked and reveals the corresponding list in the 'subject' column.
3. From this new list another random item is selected
4. This reveals another list in the 'project' column
5. A random item from the 'project' column reveals a preview image above.

Here is a simplified version of the scripts I am working with.
http://jsfiddle.net/uRd6N/19/

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've got the first part of what I am trying to do. http://jsfiddle.net/uRd6N/22   Can anyone help figure out how to repeat the script for the second column items?

Answer (score 0):

Your process doesn't sound like a bad way to go. Have you tried it?

Comment: I've tried somethings but I am very new to writing scripts and it hasn't been working out. I am not sure how to make the 'randomitem' that the first script produces to be read by the second script automatically.

Comment: Going of of the jsFiddle, how about doing `$(randomitem).click();` instead of `$(randomitem).addClass('subject');` ?

Comment: It does not seem to work. Is the .click supposed to automatically simulate a user click? How would you make the second script understand the 'randomitem' in the same way as it does '#medium a'?

Comment: Well at that point `randomitem` is a DOM Element, so `$(randomitem)` would create a jQuery object. Does your code look for hover or click for medium links?

Comment: Okay I've replaced the '#medium a' with 'randomitem' as the jQuery object. Also changed the mouseover to a click but there is still something not working. If $(randomitem).addClass('current') is added before $(randomitem).click() you can tell that the script is still selecting random items but why doesn't it add the class of current with the new script? http://jsfiddle.net/bA2Ze/2/

Comment: All your code does is add a click listener to the random item. You need to add the click listener to every link, and then call `$(randomitem).click()` which executes the click function.